# How to 'specify Apple private key' in firebase authentication settings

Tags: firebase, authentication, apple-developer

I'm painfully working my way through adding the about-to-be-required Apple sign in method for my first react native (managed expo) app.  I've got the expo bit working and am now trying to hook it up to the firebase method by using the identityToken I've got from the expo bit (hoping that will work).  However, the problem I have is that I've generated the required Apple log in private key but the firebase docs say to 'specify it' in the authentication panel where I'm activating the Apple sign in method.  There's a box with '---BEGIN PRIVATE KEY--- and ---END PRIVATE KEY---' in it but I have no idea how to get the key into the box...!!!  I'm sure I'm being dense, but I've not done this before and have been googling it for the last half hour and can find no ref to it...  I have the private key (.P8 file) on my hard drive but if I try to copy and paste it I just get the filename and that's just giving me the 'needs a private key' error.  Can anyone please help??!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yayyyyy!!  It's a text file!!  I opened it with TextEdit!  Found the answer here in case anyone else is tearing their hair out....[What is the file with .p8 extension? (APNs Auth Key / JWT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49326118/what-is-the-file-with-p8-extension-apns-auth-key-jwt)